# Transitive group action on Sylow subgroups

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, sylow-theory

Let's say we have $5$ Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$ for some $p$. This induces a group homomorphism $f: G\to S_{5}$ if we let $G$ act on the set $Syl_p$ by conjugation.

> Question: I'm not 100% sure if I understand why it follows that $|f(G)|\geq 5$ from the fact that the group action is transitive.

I would say that we have at least permutations $\sigma$ with $\sigma (i)=j$ for each $i,j\in\{1,\dots,5\}$. So for example, if we fix $i=1$ we get 5 permutations for this that cannot be the same since they are bijections. Is that correct? Maybe someone else has more insight and would care sharing his point of view?

Comment: So $p=2{{{}}}$.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $p=2$ is the only prime that satisfies $5 \equiv 1 \bmod p$.

Comment: Yeah but that has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the *class formula*: there results from this formula that, for any group $G$ operating on a set $X$, the cardinal of an orbit is a divisor of $|G|$.

Comment: Okay, so all Sylow-$p$-subgroups are in the same Orbit with length $5$. But how does this mean that the image of $G$ has at least 5 elements? Maybe it's too late and I'm too tired.

Comment: If $5$ is a divisor of $|f(G)|$, it implies $|f(G)|\ge 5$, don't you think?

Comment: Didn't we just say $5$ is a divisor of $|G|$?

Comment: In my answer, it was a general notation (for any group $G$...). It is applied to *your* $f(G)$ as a subgroup of $S_5$.

Comment: How so? G acts on the set of Sylow subgroups, not $f(G)$.